# Windows explorer force excel to import

Tags: windows, excel

I want to add a context menu item to my windows explorer (Windows 7) in order to import the selected file to excel and start the import dialog.

I managed to add the entry following this guide:
http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/

But when it opens the file, the import dialog is skipped and the file is opened in the spreadsheet.

EDIT: I searched for exe switches, but the ones that I found are kind of useless for this!
EDIT2: More background as asked by ElectricLlama

Extra background:
Will need to import a lot of text files to excel. Not CSV
For now they are fixed width, but they will for sure change in the immediate future.
I'm opening them to convert them and add some extra information as columns.
Program X generates a table with white space for spacing ----> Excel to format this table and add information ----> Program Y opens the excel file directly

Comment: You might be able to build a VBScript that uses the Excel object model to do all this. Post back if you are interested.

Comment: Yes I would be interested on the VB script! Would it be called through windows or inside excel?

Comment: It would be called from windows - let me do some investigation and get back to you.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a programmatic way to make the import dialog appear. Are all the files the same? Are they fixed width? Are you opening them to convert them, to edit them and save in a different format or just view them?

Comment: Responded with edit, ElectricLlama!

Comment: What is the nature of this extra data that you are adding? Can you automate that process or does someone need to inspect each file and manually add the extra data?

Comment: So I guess you are trying to acertain if it is possible to parse the data from this file and build something that does not need to go to excel, right?

I didn't do this at the beginning since the original file was somewhat weird in the sense that there was extra double quotes and strange spacing. But what I did was write a python script to handle the parsing and then send an os signal to open the final CSV file.

Should I write up this process as an answer to my question?

Comment: I think it would be of great benefit - how many times have you had a hit on a search term to find there was no answer? - Please do write it up and accept as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I made an option in the windows registry (using regedit) to have it launch the python script which would handle parsing and calling Excel.exe. The file type was files without extension and python is in the PATH windows variable. Also the regedit export escapes quotes (if you wondering about that):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\import with excel]
@="Convert and Open with Excel"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\import with excel\command]
@="python \"path to python script\" \"%1\""
```

The python script is very messy and very tailored to my needs, but here it is:

```
import csv, os, sys

#If there are no arguments stop everything
if len(sys.argv) > 0:
    file = sys.argv[1]
else: sys.exit()

fileout = file + ".csv"

data = open(file, "r")
open(fileout, 'w').close() #cleans the file

dataout = open(fileout, "a")

# using the python csv lib, please look for info on it for further explanation
with open(fileout, 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel')

# I needed a special handling for the first line, that's why I used the i < 2
    i = 1
    for line in data:
        line = line.split()
        lineout = [] # clean the list after each line is parsed
        if i < 2: lineout.append("")
        for item in line:
             if item != "\"": lineout.append(item.replace("\"", ""))
        spamwriter.writerow(lineout)

        i += 1
data.close()
dataout.close()

# launches excel.exe with the fileout argument
os.system("start Excel.exe \""+ fileout + "\"")
```

I then get the csv file opened in excel as I wanted. It's actually faster this way then having to manually select every option in the Excel import window.